# Use λ,φ,α,... in the jupyter notebook, just as in julia

Tags: python, ipython, julia, jupyter

As some of you probably know, you can use λ,φ,α,.., in any julia script. Couldnt this also be possible for python? I would use julia, but there are still some packages from python which I would have to wrap.

Best wishes

Comment: Yes, `λ = 1` is legal python code. Did you think of trying it? If so, did you get an error?

Comment: Non-ASCII identifiers are only allowed in Python 3.

Comment: @jwodder no Python 2 accepts non-ascii identifiers.  You just need to identify the file encoding at the top of the script. (e.g. `# coding=utf-8`).

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon: That lets you use non-ASCII characters inside strings in the source code without having to use `\x` or `\u` escapes, but Python 2 will still give you a syntax error if you try to do `λ = 1`.

Comment: @jwodder you're correct, been a while since I've used non-ascii characters as identifiers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 supports λ,φ,α and many other [Unicode characters in identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support) (as mentioned by @jwodder).  In jupyter notebook, you can access these characters by typing

```
\<character name><tab>
```

Example

```
\alpha<tab> = 1
# α = 1
```

---

Not all Unicode characters can be used as variable names, e.g. emojis:

```
>>> ♥ = "love"
  File "<ipython-input-29-97d253080b57>", line 1
    ♥ = "love"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

However, letter-like characters are allowed, particularly in foreign languages:

```
>>> αγαπώ = "love"
>>> люблю = "love"
>>> 愛 = "love"
```

See also David Beazley's [talk](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2010/pycon-2010--mastering-python-3-i-o.html) *Mastering Python 3 I/O* for more on practical uses of Unicode.

- REF 001: [Unicode variables
  names](https://python-3-for-scientists.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python3_user_features.html#unicode-variable-names)
- REF 002: [PEP 3131 - Supporting Non-ASCII Identifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)
- REF 003: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support)